# Align TextView bottom of Tabbed layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to align a TextView to the bottom of Tab Layout, so it is flush with the bottom of the screen.  It's basically going to be the equivalent of a browser status bar, so it's only going to be a couple pixels high with some text in it.  This is what I have so far:

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:padding="0dp"
>
>     <TabWidget
>         android:id="@android:id/tabs"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>         android:padding="0dp"
>         android:background="@drawable/tab_bg_selector" 
>      />           
>      <FrameLayout
>         android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>         android:padding="0dp" 
>      />
>         <TextView 
>     android:id="@+id/status"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:text="Last Updated"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
>     android:background="#cccccc"
> />         
> </LinearLayout>
>  <RelativeLayout
>     android:orientation="vertical"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>     android:layout_height="10dp"
>     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">        
> <TextView 
>     android:id="@+id/status"
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>     android:background="#cccccc"
>     />
>  </RelativeLayout>
> </TabHost>
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set your TextView's height and width to "fill_parent". This means that the base of the view itself is at the bottom, but the text within the view is probably at the top of its layout. You should set the height to "wrap_content". With the view only as tall as it needs to be, it should appear at the bottom of its layout.